What do you call a specific 'snapshot' of the way a group of levers, knobs, and buttons are set?
An example paragraph with the word that may not even exist:
"I went to look at the old factory, and saw that the <MAGIC_WORD> of the controls showed that it would have been making chairs. But the production records indicated they were making tables, instead. So it may be that someone came in and messed with the controls, or it could be an error in the readout."
Words I considered, but rejected:
Several ordinary words seem like they could fit, but all of the ones I can think of feel inadequate to emphasize that they are for "The way all these hardware adjusting controls are currently set."
"Arrangement" came to mind first, but felt like it was merely talking about a layout of the controls. You can arrange a display so that, say, a knob for volume is located on any part of a console, and this would be an arrangement. But I am wanting to refer to the levels at which every control 'widget' is set.
"Setup" seem the same sort of failing as "arrangement."
"Settings" also came to mind, but this felt so abstract that it didn't even need the hardware.  I want to emphasize that the hardware itself has been physically adjusted to match a set of data (that is, the Settings).
Thesaurus attempts that proved unfruitful:
I searched thesaurus.com for all of the above words, and got nothing useful.  Additionally, I tried the following words : snapshot, picture, instantiation, reify, exhibit, actualize,
and exteriorize.
Ideal results:
Ideally, I'm looking for a noun here.  However, if such a word only exists in some other form (e.g. verb), I'm happy to hear it.
I'm looking for one word because I want brevity, but a compound word / two words is okay, too, if they are very short.
Heck, I'd be fine with a clever (but short) portmanteau, like "levarrangement." However, that's long, clunky, and really only feels like it is for levers, specifically. (Again, I'd be okay with a similarly 'narrow' result, if it was quite short.)

You may not do better than 'setting': << setting sense 2. [countable noun]:
A setting is one of the positions to which the controls of a device such as a cooker, stove, or heater can be adjusted. >> [Collins]

What about layout?

Strangely, if you put "configuration" into thesaurus.com, it gives you "arrangement"  but not the other way round.  Collins is the same.  Roget's doesn't put them in the same list (at least in the old editions online); mine at home is not exactly new.  Merriam-Webster does return "configuration" if you ask for "arrangement"

This isn't a word that means what you want in general, but in context, "the positions of the controls" would work perfectly, since you are talking about physical controls which are changed by changing their positions.

This is a configuration. From Mirriam-Webster:

Configuration (noun) 1b: something (such as a figure, contour, pattern, or apparatus) that results from a particular arrangement of parts or components

It is used the same way for (virtual) controls in a computer program. You go into a settings menu to modify the configuration of parameters. In the physical equivalent of buttons and knobs, each control manipulates one or more parameters in your hypothetical factory machinery- belt speed, gear ratio, air pressure of a compressor, temperature of a heating element, and so on.

It probably also helps that this is an old word for this.  Depending on context this may be more desirable than other terms which mostly take this meaning in a computer context.

+1 - a good word for the manual I guess - latinate n'all.  My (UK) English prefers setting.

setting usually refers to 1 particular control (button, lever) state, so you should say it in plural - "settings". However, we usually prefer singular form for naming something, so in this respect configuration would be better.

@AgniusVasiliauskas - yes, individual controls may be set, so too can a machine (with multiple variable controls) be set (and thereby have a setting).  In fact, altering several controls to do this rather than that or the other is more of a 'setting' than a configuration, which to my mind implies a more in depth alteration of the way the machine itself is put together.

OP already said that settings "...felt so abstract that it didn't even need the hardware. I want to emphasize that the hardware itself has been physically adjusted..." Settings sounds alright to me in general, but configuration can be used for physical objects. You might have a set of LEGO blocks that can be either a car or a plane, depending on their arrangement or configuration (and OP ruled out arrangement already as well)

@automaton - tbh I'm perplexed by the OP.  The question uses the obvious word appropriately and then dismisses it for being 'too abstract'.  Settings, in my mind, are not abstract at all, they are the values of variables which can be adjusted by turning knobs and flicking switches (either physically, or these days more likely, digitally).

Another option is state. Simple switches have two states - on and off. But state is used in much broader situations as well. The position of all the control surfaces on an aircraft (or their commanded positions) is the control state vector. Vector here meaning only that there are a whole list of surfaces. The position and velocity (both 6 dof) relative to the ground is the navigation state vector.
So it's just as normal to talk about the state of an entire control panel's inputs and outputs as it is to talk about the state of a single switch.
This is why we have the "State of the Union" address.

while strictly true, this doesn't seem like something that would be used in this context

I think "the state of the controls" sounds perfectly natural and gets the point across well.

@kaya3: "control state" is shorter and (I think) a common phrase.

In Math, also in Computer Science, "state machine" has a specific meaning (applicable to the OP's example) and carries with it the concept of a given "state" being just one of many in some specific set of possible "states."

@JamesStein Perhaps, but the phrasing the OP is looking for is "the [blank] of the controls".

"State" is correct, where "configuration" is not. Configuration includes modes as well.

+1, “state” was the word I immediately thought of when reading the question

Agreed. The base state, the ready state, the current state. configuration state...All are ways to describe the way things are arranged at a current time, or the way they would be arranged if you wanted the machine to be in a specific configuration.

+1 "State" -- thermodynamics uses the concepts of "microstate" and "macrostate"  and "state variables" and the "equation of state" all in compatible ways to the OP's request.

While I’ve no doubt, based on the comments here, that state is used this way, I would – as a lay reader who is not familiar with this terminological field at all – quite possibly either misunderstand or fail entirely to understand it in the given context (though the on/off state of a switch is perfectly natural and familiar even to me). Control state vector would certainly be completely meaningless to me. @kaya3 To me, ‘the state of the controls’ sounds like a description of whether the control units are in good condition or worn out.

@fectin Could you clarify? What are ‘modes’ in this context that are included in a configuration (but apparently should not be)? What modes do knobs and levers have?

@JanusBahsJacquet Configuration is frequently used to describe equipment's options list or custom features as delivered by the factory. I can buy a Deere Gator configured for spraying. https://www.deere.com/en/turf-sprayers/ What it is doing depends on the state of the sprayer control panel.  If forced to separate the two, I'd say state is preferred for things that are variables during operation; while configuration changes are more involved and would mean shutting things down. But the verb configure certainly applies to both, ie. configure the flaps for landing.

@PhilSweet Ah, I see what you mean now. I agree that I too would say that I buy something with a specific configuration (≈ set of fittings and accessories for a particular purpose), not a particular state.

These could be their settings.  From the Collins Dictionary:

A setting is one of the positions to which the controls of a device such as a cooker, stove, or heater can be adjusted.


OP gives this, and I echoed it.

@EdwinAshworth You’re right. I do still want to emphasize that this isn’t related to a set of things, and doesn’t feel abstract to me.

I think the word you're looking for is 'setup'.
The machine can be configured to produce chairs or tables, but the configuration cannot be saved, it exists as a span across 4 dimensions.  You can establish a different configuration by changing the setup, which moves the machine from one configuration to another.  The setup includes the settings, but may also include the sequence in which the settings are applied to the controls.  If the setup can be performed in any order, you can take a snap-shot of the settings for that setup, and you might be able to reload the snapshot and apply it to the settings to restore the configuration.  If you mess around with the settings, you get a different setup, which may not produce a useful configuration.

In music specifically, especially with synthesizers, this is known as a patch.

Not sure that would apply here: patching usually involves connections/cables/patch panels.

With analog modular synths that's the precise and original meaning, but the usage of the word goes far beyond that. For example, here's a discussion about finding patches for the Minimoog, which has no patch cables to speak of, just dials and switches. Here's another discussion where the word "patch" refers to the configuration of a software synth.

This can be called a preset:

A setting on a device that is adjusted or applied before use or by the manufacturer, especially on electronic audio or video equipment. (Oxford Languages via Google)
A position that can be set using the controls of a piece of equipment. (Cambridge Dictionary)

The word "preset" is more specific than "configuration"; it is typically used for intended configurations, particularly those which can be loaded from a device's memory, but it could also include configurations which have been recorded on paper and manually entered.
So if the factory controls are set in a known position for making tables, this word would fit. However, if the controls are scrambled as if by someone changing them randomly, and it's only a coincidence that the configuration is valid for making tables, then you wouldn't use this word in the given context.

Mode. "I went to look at the old factory, and saw that it was in  chair production mode. But the xxxproductionxxx records indicated they were making tables, instead. So it may be that someone came in and messed with the controls, or it could be an error in the readout."

Another word that can describe the settings of a control panel is a tuning. It somewhat calls to mind the notion of adjusting dials on a radio or other audio equipment. It in a way connotes an adjustment to some group of continuous settings, rather than a wholesale change of mode - you might tune a system to run faster or slower, but probably not to accomplish an entirely different task, for example.
This word also carries the connotation of a purposeful and precise configuration, unlike some of the more neutral options which could describe even a random setting.

Maybe late and maybe not the best ( I would go with either "Configuration" or "Settings" already suggested in previous answers) But just because nobody else mentioned it so you also have the term
"Scheme"
.. that might be applied in similar situations, and can also be used in conjunction with the above answers as in "..their Configuration scheme.." or even  "..their Settings scheme.." which might sound a bit weird to a specific ear but can work.
Other two options ( again, only because nobody mentioned ) :  " Formation " and " Composition " also come to mind, but might have the same drawback mentioned of "Layout".

'Snapshot' itself seems perfect.
Consider a fairly old-fashioned movie featuring a computer with umpty flashing lights.
What could those lights usefully mean to a human operator until the machine failed, freezing the flashing lights into a fixed pattern?
Isn't that a 'snapshot'?
How does that not describe the situation about which you ask?

"snapshot" has already been suggested https://english.stackexchange.com/a/621118/44619

@Mari-LouA Thanks and if that refers back to Graham, above, I apologize for wasting everyione's time by missing .

There's also "assemblage" and "array."
Collins gives definitions:

An assemblage of people or things is a collection of them.
[formal]
He had an assemblage of old junk cars filling the backyard.

And

An array of different things or people is a large number or wide range of them.  As the deadline approached she experienced a bewildering array of emotions.


This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

The OP asked for language suggestions, and I was suggesting language.

You should have been giving suggestions with citations/examples in context and demonstrated how your particular suggestions are appropriate to the OP's context.

Many good answers. My answer is profile.
BTW, In AI image creation it is called generation data (which strikes me as being a minimal effort at creating a nomenclature).

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You already said it.
Snapshot
is often used as a summary of the state/configuration of the system.
It's the correct word to use in audio contexts (see this link). The original method was taking a photo. This has since been extended to include all automation and other settings, but "snapshot" is still the word used in the audio industry.
In any other context though, it should be just as well understood. For example, we also talk about snapshots of virtual machines.

I would argue that Snapshot fits best when the current configuration (which is the accepted answer) is recorded in some manner. It becomes a snapshot after recording, but if no recording exists there still needs to be a name for it.

OP gives this, and has already rejected it.

In software environments this is often referred to as a...
Bookmark
The idea being that a particular configuration is saved as a named bookmark and you can return to the bookmark at a later stage.
There are lots of other words and ideas that potentially fall out of the same concept. For example buttons that allow "reset to default" or the notion of saving a file or setting.
